# Swift calling public class in another file

Tags: ios, class, swift, public

In Swift programming. I have created a public class called Array3d and is inside Array3d.swift file. My ViewController2.swift create a variable called dog by using the Array3d class and i println(dog). However my console does not show the values of the array of dog but show FYP_Table.Array3D instead.

I have created a 3D Array Called dog and inserted some values into it. Now i want to print it to my debugger output. But does not work.

```
// Array3d.swift 
    public class Array3D {
        var zs:Int, ys:Int, xs:Int
        var matrix: [Float]

        init(zs: Int, ys:Int, xs:Int) {
            self.zs = zs
            self.ys = ys
            self.xs = xs
            matrix = Array(count:zs*ys*xs, repeatedValue:0)
        }

        subscript(z:Int, y:Int, x:Int) -> Float {
            get {
                return matrix[ z * ys * xs + y * xs + x ]
            }
            set {
                matrix[ z * ys * xs + y * xs + x ] = newValue
            }
        }

//ViewController2.swift

    class ViewController2: UITableViewController {

    var dog = Array3D(zs: 3, ys: 3, xs: 3)


    override func viewDidLoad() {

    dog[1,0,0] = 1
    dog[0,4,0] = 2
    dog[0,0,4] = 3
    dog[0,4,4] = 4

      for z in 0..<3 {
       for y in 0..<3 {
        for x in 0..<3 {
         println(self.dog)
               }
             }
           }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesn't have a `description`, so it's just printing out the default representation.

```
func description() -> String {
  return String(format: "Array3D zs:%d ys:%d xs:%d", self.zs, self.ys, self.zs)
}
```

Comment: Just an addition: it would be more "swiftish", if you use: return "Array3D zs: \\(zs) ys: \\(ys) xs: \\(xs)"

Comment: Probably; I've never actually programmed anything in swift. ;)

Comment: Technically, you have to make your class implement the `Printable` category which means implementing description (as a property) as well as adding it the declaration of the class as seen in @fred's link.

Comment: Hi.. But i would want to return my array with the values in it, for example dog[z,y,x]. Then in ViewController2, i will want to print my 3D array out, and i will use a for loop. How do i return my array with values in it? Sorry if i ask a simple question, a beginner in programming here..

Comment: Does the code provided above present a specific problem that you can describe? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry @IanMacDonald. I've edited. My 3D array called dog has some values in it. And now i want to print it into my debugger output. It does not show the array correctly..

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output that you expect?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I have figured out already. I could not get what i want because i use println instead of print.. println will print whatever is inside the bracket and goes to the next line. But print will print whatever is inside the bracket and not go to next line.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to implement the `Printable` protocol (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH11-SW1)), which is simply a read-only property named `description`.

```
var description : String {
    return String(format: "Array3D zs:%d ys:%d xs:%d", zs, ys, zs)
}
```